# How can I get tables which using [DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP] in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Some of my tables are using `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for create_time field in my `mysql` DB.

```
`create_time` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'data create time'
```

And I want to  select all my tables which use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_DEFAULT = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
-- AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a backup and find it in your output SQL, or go to the data dictionary and find the value in `Information_Schema.Columns` table, column `Column_Default`